# Get current index from foreach loop

Tags: c#, silverlight, for-loop, foreach

Using C# and Silverlight

How do I get the index of the current item in the list?

Code:

```
IEnumerable list = DataGridDetail.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();


foreach (var row in list)
{
  bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)DataGridDetail.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;
  if (IsChecked)
  {

    // Here I want to get the index or current row from the list                   

  }
}
```

How to achieve this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IEnumerable list = DataGridDetail.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
List<string> lstFile = new List<string>();

int i = 0;
foreach (var row in list)
{
bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)DataGridDetail.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row)).IsChecked;
if (IsChecked)
{
  MessageBox.show(i);
--Here i want to get the index or current row from the list                   

}
 ++i;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of using a `foreach` if you can use a `for`... :P

Answer (score 28):

You can't, because `IEnumerable` doesn't have an index at all... **if you are sure your enumerable has less than `int.MaxValue` elements** *(or `long.MaxValue` if you use a `long` index)*, you can:

1. Don't use foreach, and use a `for` loop, converting your `IEnumerable` to a generic enumerable first:

   ```
   var genericList = list.Cast<object>();
   for(int i = 0; i < genericList.Count(); ++i)
   {
      var row = genericList.ElementAt(i);
      /* .... */
   }
   ```
2. Have an external index:

   ```
   int i = 0;
   foreach(var row in list)
   {
      /* .... */
      ++i;
   }
   ```
3. Get the index via Linq:

   ```
   foreach(var rowObject in list.Cast<object>().Select((r, i) => new {Row=r, Index=i}))
   {
     var row = rowObject.Row;
     var i = rowObject.Index;
     /* .... */    
   }
   ```

In your case, since your `IEnumerable` is not a generic one, I'd rather use the `foreach` with external index (second method)... otherwise, you may want to make the `Cast<object>` outside your loop to convert it to an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Your datatype is not clear from the question, but I'm assuming `object` since it's an items source (it could be `DataGridRow`)... you may want to check if it's directly convertible to a generic `IEnumerable<object>` without having to call `Cast<object>()`, but I'll make no such assumptions.

---

#### All this said:

The concept of an "index" is foreign to an `IEnumerable`. An `IEnumerable` can be potentially infinite. In your example, you are using the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid`, so more likely your `IEnumerable` is just a list of objects (or `DataRows`), with a finite (and hopefully less than `int.MaxValue`) number of members, but `IEnumerable` can represent anything that can be enumerated (and an enumeration can potentially never end).

Take this example:

```
public static IEnumerable InfiniteEnumerable()
{
  var rnd = new Random();
  while(true)
  {
    yield return rnd.Next();
  }
}
```

So if you do:

```
foreach(var row in InfiniteEnumerable())
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Your `foreach` will be infinite: if you used an `int` (or `long`) index, you'll eventually overflow it (and unless you use an `unchecked` context, it'll throw an exception if you keep adding to it: even if you used `unchecked`, the index would be meaningless also... at some point -when it overflows- the index will be the same for two different values).

So, while the examples given work for a typical usage, I'd rather not use an index at all if you can avoid it.

Comment: Option 3 is stupendous. I love it!

Comment: @pnizzle It's not exactly optimal as it loops the list twice...

Comment: @cvbattum no, it doesn't... what makes you think it loops twice? (edit: I just [tested it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a3NWuT), and it definitely doesn't loop twice)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.105).aspx)

```
list = list.Cast<object>().Select( (v, i) => new {Value= v, Index = i});

foreach(var row in list)
{
    bool IsChecked = (bool)((CheckBox)DataGridDetail.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row.Value)).IsChecked;
    row.Index ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here, 1. Use `for` instead for `foreach` for iteration.But in your case the collection is IEnumerable and the upper limit of the collection is unknown so foreach will be the best option. so i prefer to use another integer variable to hold the iteration count: here is the code for that:

```
int i = 0; // for index
foreach (var row in list)
{
    bool IsChecked;// assign value to this variable
    if (IsChecked)
    {    
       // use i value here                
    }
    i++; // will increment i in each iteration
}
```